# How to inner join tables in laravel php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have this query which is

```
SELECT * FROM books b 
INNER JOIN categories c ON b.category_id = c.id 
WHERE c.category_name = 'Comics'
```

thus is passed by parameter

```
SELECT * FROM books b 
INNER JOIN categories c ON b.category_id = c.id 
WHERE c.category_name = ?
```

I tried in Laravel like this

```
writer::join('categories','categories.id','=','writers.category_id')
  ->where('categories.category_name','Comics')
  ->get();
```

And with parameter

```
writer::join('categories','categories.id','=','writers.category_id')
  ->where(['categories.category_name' => $cat])
  ->get();
```

I didn't get any data in Laravel! Is there any mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
writer::join('categories','categories.id','=','writers.category_id')
->where([
  ['categories.category_name', '=', $cat]
])->get();
```

or

```
writer::join('categories','categories.id','=','writers.category_id')
->where('categories.category_name', $cat)
->get();
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to add paginate(); to it?

Comment: so instead of ->get() just use the ->paginate()